# Converting Z3 CNF formula into list-of-lists representation using Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

Given a Z3 formula in CNF, is it possible to convert it into a list-of-lists representation using Z3Py? I'd like to do this for easier access and manipulation of literals. If Python were a functional language, I might do something like

```
def cnf2list(fm) :
  match fm with
  | And(P,Q) -> cnf2list(P) + cnf2list(Q)
  | P -> clause2list(P)

def clause2list(fm) :
  match fm with
  | Or(P,Q) -> clause2list(P) + clause2list(Q)  
  | P -> [P]
```

But I'm not sure I can do this in Python. Is it possible to perform pattern matching like above (or use some entirely different method) to obtain a list-of-lists representation of a Z3 CNF formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pattern matching, but z3py allows to inspect Z3 expressions:

```
def clause2list(expr):
    if z3.is_const(expr):
        return [str(expr)]
    elif z3.is_or(expr):
        return [atom for disjunct in expr.children()
                     for atom in clause2list(disjunct)]
    else:
        assert False, ('not supported', expr)

x, y, z = z3.Bools('x y z')
print(clause2list(z3.Or(x, y, z)))
# ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Support for negations, conjunctions, and true and false literals is left as an exercise :)
See [z3.py](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3.py), ctrl-f "def is_".

Note that my implementation returns lists of variable names instead of Z3 variables themselves. That's because of [Christoph Wintersteiger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869966/christoph-wintersteiger) warning. If you intend to do any processing on these lists, symbolic `__eq__` is most likely not what you want.

---

I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but if you are generating CNFs yourself, consider producing them in the list-of-lists form from the start. It's easier to convert a list of lists to a Z3 expression than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Python expert by any means, but simply putting brackets [...] around the expressions and then using the + operator for concatenation does construct some lists, e.g., like so:

```
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
z = Int('z')

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
lst = [x] + [y]
print(lst)
s = sum(lst)
print(s)
lst.reverse()
print(lst)
print(x in lst)
```

However, the element comparsions seem to give some unexpected results, for instance these:

```
print(z in lst)
print(lst.count(x))
```

At this point I'm not sure whether I'm using Python lists in an unexpected way or whether that's a Z3 Python API problem.

Comment: This is inevitable consequence of custom `__eq__`.

Comment: List membership test `x in xs` is roughly equivalent to `any(bool(x == el) for el in xs)`, and `bool(<some Z3 expression>)` is always true according to [these rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__).

This behavior is certainly not problematic enough to sacrifice the convenience of symbolic `==`, but I think minor improvement is possible. Consider adding method `__bool__` that throws an exception, to prevent such usage altogether. I'm pretty sure that the majority of cases where symbolic boolean expression is used in a concrete boolean context are mistakes.

Comment: That's great, thanks for explaining that @VladShcherbina! I'll go ahead an add the __bool__ method.